# typescript class, this is undefined in method while accessing variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have this class in typescript

```
class SlowQueriesController {
  $http
  constructor($http, $routeParams) {
    this.$http = $http;

    ..... some other code ....

    this.$http.get('/api/metrics/findByType/' + $routeParams.application + '/METER').then(response => {
      this.meters = response.data;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.meters.length; i++) {
        fillInMeterData(this.meters[i]);
      }
    });
  }

  function fillInMeterData(meter) {
    this.$http.get('/api/meterData/values/' + meter._id).then(response => {
      ... some code ...
    });
  }
}
```

The problem i get is that in the method fillInMeterData where i am accessing this.$http, this is undefined.

any idea what am i doing wrong. Pardon my very shallow knowledge of typescript, i am still learning.

Comment: How can you have a function inside a class? The compiler should complain about that.

Comment: It didn't complain for me, would you suggest me the alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, The problem was that there were methods before fillInMeterData which were not declared properly (they were declared like 'function methodName()')

Once i fixed all the methods in the class to follow the syntax everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

In typescript the class methods should not contain the `function` keyword, and the compiler should have complained about you using it, like in [this playground of a stripped version of your code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20SlowQueriesController%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(%24http%2C%20%24routeParams)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20fillInMeterData(meter)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D):

```
class SlowQueriesController {
    constructor($http, $routeParams) { }

    function fillInMeterData(meter) {} // ERROR: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
}
```

Your code should look like this:

```
class SlowQueriesController {
    $http
    constructor($http, $routeParams) {
        this.$http = $http;

        ..... some other code ....

        this.$http.get('/api/metrics/findByType/' + $routeParams.application + '/METER').then(response => {
            this.meters = response.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.meters.length; i++) {
                this.fillInMeterData(this.meters[i]);
            }
        });
    }

    fillInMeterData(meter) {
        this.$http.get('/api/meterData/values/' + meter._id).then(response => {
            ... some code ...
        });
    }
}
```

The differences being:

1. No `function` keyword for the `fillInMeterData` method
2. When calling this method, use `this.fillInMeterData`

Comment: i tried that but i get this error in the compiler then "Failed to lint: app/slowQueries/slowQueries.controller.ts[102, 25]: Missing semicolon.".......  Line number 102 is where i have the method fillInMeterData

Comment: That's not a compiler error but a lint error. Which linter are you using? Can you update your question with the exact code which produces this error?

Comment: how do i find out which linter i am using? Basically i used yeoman generator-angular-fullstack to generate the basic structure and modified for my usage. Pasting the entire code will be very convoluting, i can email you the code if you want.

Comment: It's not about your code, it's about your setup. How do you compile your typescript files? For example, if you just compile them with `tsc` does it work?